# android push notification c2dm

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have successfully implemented the android push notification using google c2dm.
  the problem is,when i push the message from the server i am getting success full deveice id. but the device some time receive push message,some time did not receive.(wifi is fully active)

i want the app to receive all the push message with out any push message lose,becoz each notification is important.

Is there any special parameter need to set or hw i would i confirm that device successfully received the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"C2DM makes no guarantees about delivery or the order of messages. So, for example, while you might use this feature to tell an instant messaging application that the user has new messages, you probably would not use it to pass the actual messages."

But you can try to play with 2 parameters:

collapse_key
An arbitrary string that is used to collapse a group of like messages when the device is offline, so that only the last message gets sent to the client. This is intended to avoid sending too many messages to the phone when it comes back online. Note that since there is no guarantee of the order in which messages get sent, the "last" message may not actually be the last message sent by the application server. Required.

delay_while_idle
If included, indicates that the message should not be sent immediately if the device is idle. The server will wait for the device to become active, and then only the last message for each collapse_key value will be sent. Optional.